# How can I change the admin path in SilverStripe 3.1.x?

Tags: security, path, admin, silverstripe

Can anyone tell me how I can change the path to the admin on SilverStripe 3.1.x?  A site I built has a medium risk security issue outstanding from a security scan - apparently the path /admin is too easy to guess.

The recommendation is to:

> Modify the link, name or location of the administrative login page so it cannot be easily
>   identified/guessed by an unauthorized user. If only internal users require access, implement
>   additional restrictions to restrict access from the Internet.

I found something for SilverStripe 2.x here: http://www.silverstripe.org/archive/show/3550 , but I need something similar for SilverStripe 3.1.x

Comment: well if you do in cms a $grep -lr 'admin' *

 _config/routes.yml
 code/controllers/AssetAdmin.php
 code/controllers/CMSMain.php
 code/controllers/ReportAdmin.php
 code/model/SiteTree.php
 code/model/VirtualPage.php
 code/reports/Report.php
 css/CMSMain.css
 css/screen.css
 javascript/AssetAdmin.js
 javascript/CMSPageHistoryController.js
 ...

total of 86 hits if you count tests and lang.

Comment: Thanks, but then I'd be modifying the core codebase all over the place.  Is there not a way to achieve this by adding config/routing options into a config file rather than hacking away at the core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not fully test but adding those into your `config.yml` seem to do the trick:

```
Director:
  rules:
    'admin': ''
    'fancyLongAdminURL': 'AdminRootController'
AdminRootController:
  url_base: 'fancyLongAdminURL'
LeftAndMain:
  url_base: 'fancyLongAdminURL'
```

Only thing I can see not working is the `myProfile` link in the top left corner. But that's because the url is hard coded in the template `LeftAndMain_Menu.ss`, which you could create your own.

**Edit:** The above **should** work fine for the framework. For the CMS and other modules, this will have to be investigated and may need more classes/templates overrides, for example:

- The `CMS` seems to have hardcoded admin url in
  `Intall_deleteinstallfiles.ss`, `AssetAdmin.js`, `VirtualPage.php`,
  `SiteTree.php`, `AssetAdmin.php`, `routes.yml`....
- The `Reports` module have it hardcoded in `Report.php`

In those cases maybe a URLRewrite might be more convenient until this is implemented in the core.

**Update:** This has now been merged into the master branch so it should make its way into the next 4.0 release:
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/3274

Comment: colymba - thank you so much!  You're a legend!  That worked perfectly.  I knew there had to be a simple way of doing this.

Comment: For the benefit of others looking to do the same thing, to change myProfile link, I copied LeftAndMain_Menu.ss from framework/admin/templates/Includes/LeftAndMain_Menu.ss to mysite/templates/Includes/LeftAndMain_Menu.ss and then I changed line 15 from 
<a href="{$AbsoluteBaseURL}admin/myprofile" class="profile-link"> 

to 

<a href="{$AbsoluteBaseURL}fancyLongAdminURL/myprofile" class="profile-link">

Comment: I noticed that the links in the Reports section didn't update - they still have /admin in the links, but I'm guessing there must be another reason for that.

Comment: Updated the answer above, but in short, the CMS has quite a few instances or hardcoded admin URLs, same for the report module...

Comment: Thanks again, colymba.  You Rock!

Comment: Just putting it out there: this **doesn't** hide the login page. That's still at `Security/login` and it's really easy to get the new login URL (in 3.1 at least). Just visit your-site.com/AdminRootController.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't currently any mechanism for changing the admin path. If this is something you really think should be in core, you could consider [raising an issue](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/issues) for it.

It's interesting that there is an issue with this. SilverStripe is used for a [large number of Government websites](https://www.cwp.govt.nz/) and the website of a major bank, so it should have passed quite a few code audits in the past.

The best course of action would be to use .htaccess or similar method to restrict access to /admin to a whitelist of IP addresses. This is far more secure than simply changing the path - "security through obfuscation" is not true security.

Comment: Thanks, irogue.  I will be implementing IP restriction too - since they require this to be done also.